# Nginx and Unicorn user permissions for socket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn

Nginx has a clearly defined way to set who the process runs as in the conf file:

```
user nobody nogroup;
```

(Though as a side question I wonder why is the group necessary? If you run the process as a user the group must be by definition the group that user belongs to, how can you define a user and a group simultaneously?)

But Unicorn doesn't seem to have this ability. As a result, in my provider's VPS, I'm logged in as root, I start nginx (which runs as user nginx, group web) and I then start unicorn (which starts as root because I am logged in as root). Unicorn makes a socket owned by root and then nginx can't read from it. How can I make unicorn run as the user unicorn in the same security group as nginx so that the socket is readable by nginx?

This is on ubuntu 12.04 64bit, unicorn v4.8.2, nginx version: nginx/1.4.6

The error is below:

```
unix:/etc/sockets/.unicorn.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 24.7.100.227, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/etc/sockets/.unicorn.sock:/", host: "xx.xx.xx.xxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah I figured it out. Its actually unnecessary. BOTH processes run as root for their master processes. Even if you configure nginx with a user parameter the master process runs as root which is the one which interacts with the socket. So my issue was actually something else (a typo in the unicorn conf file)